# How to store a chart.js chart options in another file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I have an angularJS app where I need to use a history chart in one of my app controllers. The library I am using is chart.js. Every chart has to have some initial static configuration options and the way I do this is by storing this configurations object in the controller code. But since my controller is getting bigger I was wondering if there's anyway to store such chart options in another file and import it from there since the initial options are just static data

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for *angular-chart.js*, it looks like you can configure base options in an `angular.config()` function.  Just import `ChartJsProvider` and follow the code below.

```
(function (ChartJsProvider) {
    ChartJsProvider.setOptions({ colors : [ '#803690', '#00ADF9', '#DCDCDC', '#46BFBD', '#FDB45C', '#949FB1', '#4D5360'] });
});
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, and you just want to extract a config object out of your controller and have it imported, look into `angular.value()`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#value-recipe